# Why do we need Allow when we have Require in httpd？

Tags: httpd, apache-2.4

We have directives of Require and Allow which can be used in httpd.conf.

Won't `Require ip address` work like `Allow from address ; Deny from all`?

As we can see in [this docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow), `Allow`, `Deny`, and `Order` directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Why do we still need Allow?

Comment: woa! what are you talking about here? config?

Comment: As we can see in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow.   The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache httpd 2.2, then you'll use allow and deny (order/satisfy too). If you're using Apache httpd 2.4, then you'll use Require.

In fact, mod_authz_host was rewritten betwen 2.2 and 2.4, and old behavior of Deny/Allow is now deprecated. It's still implemented with mod_access_compat, but what I've seen is this module being most of the time not enabled.

The new mod_authz_host is here to simplify access control. You can see some example here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

```
2.2 configuration:

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.org

2.4 configuration:

Require host example.org
```

Allow/Deny/Satisfy/Order should not be used anymore, and it's generally easy to convert them to Require.